# Position control in Mujoco

Tags: simulation, robotics, mujoco

Being new to Mujoco, I just created a dummy scene in mujoco for which I now try to control some of the objects in it. The scene contains a fixed table on which a movable book is places, which can be moved by controlling the actuated spatula frame:

```
xml = """
<mujoco>
  <worldbody>
    <light name="top" pos="0 0 1"/>
    
    <body name="table" pos="0 0 0.025">
      <geom name="plate" type="box" size="0.25 0.2 0.025" rgba=".8 .8 .8 1"/>
      <geom name="bound0" type="box" size=".25 .01 .05" pos="0 -.19 .075"/>
      <geom name="bound1" type="box" size=".01 .19 .05" pos="-.24 .01 .075"/>
    </body>

    <body name="booklink" pos="0 0 0.065">
      <freejoint/>
      <geom name="book" type="box" size=".1 .05 .0125" rgba="0 1 0 1" mass=".1"/>
    </body>  

    <body name="spatulalink" pos="0 0 .2">
        <joint name="transX" type="slide" axis="1 0 0" limited="true" range="-.6 .6"/>
        <joint name="transY" type="slide" axis="0 1 0" limited="true" range="-.6 .6"/>
        <joint name="transZ" type="slide" axis="0 0 1" limited="true" range="-.6 .6"/>
        <joint name="hingeX" type="hinge" axis="1 0 0" limited="true" range="-3.2 3.2"/>
        <joint name="hingeY" type="hinge" axis="0 1 0" limited="true" range="-3.2 3.2"/>
        <joint name="hingeZ" type="hinge" axis="0 0 1" limited="true" range="-3.2 3.2"/>
        <geom name="spatula" type="box" size=".05 .05 5e-4" rgba="1 1 0 1" friction=".1 .1 .1" mass=".1"/>
    </body>
  </worldbody>
  <actuator>
    <position ctrllimited="true" ctrlrange="-.6 .6" joint="transX"/>
    <position ctrllimited="true" ctrlrange="-.6 .6" joint="transY"/>
    <position ctrllimited="true" ctrlrange="-.6 .6" joint="transZ"/>
    <position ctrllimited="true" ctrlrange="-3.2 3.2" joint="hingeX"/>
    <position ctrllimited="true" ctrlrange="-3.2 3.2" joint="hingeY"/>
    <position ctrllimited="true" ctrlrange="-3.2 3.2" joint="hingeZ"/>
  </actuator>
</mujoco>
"""
model = mujoco.MjModel.from_xml_string(xml)
data = mujoco.MjData(model)
```

Now my question is how I can properly run a trajectory in this environment during which I control the robot. Naively, I tried to put some controls by directly writing into `data.qpos` and `data.qvel`. This creates the desired motions, but the objects tunnel through each other, i.e., there are collisions of the geometries, which I of course do not want. You can see a picture of this here (you see the yellow spatula object going through the boundary in collision):

[image: sim error]

Now, after some reading, I now learned that the correct way of controlling actuators / joints in Mujoco is instead to set the controls directly, which in my case would be `data.crtl = some_position_vector`. I do this as follows:

```
# Construct a BSpline to interpolate the via-points
spline_ref = BSpline_reference(data.qpos[7:], data.qvel[6:], data.time)
spline_ref.append(path, times, data.time)

with mujoco.viewer.launch_passive(model, data) as viewer:
  # Close the viewer automatically after 30 wall-seconds.
  start = time.time()
  sim_steps = int(n_steps // tau)
  i = 0
  while viewer.is_running(): #and i < sim_steps:
    # Get a target position from the reference spline using current sim state
    qreal = data.qpos[7:]
    qDot_real = data.qvel[6:]
    qref, qDotref = spline_ref.getReference(qreal, qDot_real, data.time)
    data.ctrl = q_ref
    mujoco.mj_step(model, data)

    # Pick up changes to the physics state, apply perturbations, update options from GUI.
    viewer.sync()

    # Slow down sim. for visualization
    time.sleep(1e-2)
    i += 1
```

Somehow, the movement I get from this is completely different than when I set `data.qpos` directly. Can someone explain to me how the controls can be set properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have in your model are position actuators, which apply a torque or force of `kp * (q_desired - q) - kv * qdot`. So the position is not set magically as it would when you set qpos directly.

The [defaults](https://mujoco.readthedocs.io/en/stable/XMLreference.html#actuator-position) are `kp="1"` and `kv="0"`. `kp` might be too small for your system.

Similarly to how you would on a real robot, you should tune the gains on your position actuators so you get the responsiveness you want without introducing unwanted oscillations.

Note that the kv parameter will essentially create a reference velocity of zero. If you want to track a reference velocity, as well as position, you could add extra velocity actuators to your model, and set the ctrl entries for those to your qDotref.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this excellent explanation! Just to clarify two things on this: If I wanted to control position and velocity, I would need 2 actuators per joint? Why do I observe intersecting objects, i.e. physically inaccurate behaviour when setting `qpos` directly? Is this because the position will be set at all costs that way, even if this implies a collision?

Comment: > If I wanted to control position and velocity, I would need 2 actuators per joint?

Correct.

> Why do I observe intersecting objects?

When you set qpos directly, you are telling the engine that this is the state - it doesn't have a chance to resolve collisions. Penetrations are resolved by generating forces that push the colliding objects out of each other over the following physics steps.

BTW, in MuJoCo, some shallow penetrations will always happen, as the engine won't generate any forces if there are no penetrations.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add velocity actuator to the system as actuators are SISO to use PD controller.